# Subset dataframe and groupby pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

everyone, I have a data frame such as :

```
groups  name
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
2   E
3   F
3   G
4   H
5   I
```

and from that I would like to only keep in the data frame the values that are alone in a group:

```
groups  name
2   E
4   H
5   I
```

E,H and I are alone in their respective groups.

I tried:

```
df[df.groupby(['groups']).count() == 1 ]
```

But it does not seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
df[df.groupby(['groups'])['name'].transform('size') == 1 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated`:

```
df[~df.groups.duplicated(keep=False)]

   groups name
4       2    E
7       4    H
8       5    I
```

Or, `drop_duplicates`.

```
df.drop_duplicates('groups', keep=False)

   groups name
4       2    E
7       4    H
8       5    I
```